# Removed skype still have apt get update errors about skype

Tags: apt, updates, skype

I've completely purged Skype from ubuntu 20.04 since I kept receiving the following error whenever apt-get update and couldn't find a solution:

```
Err:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
  
  Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
E: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
```

Yet, I still receive the above error when apt-get update even though I've removed the public key, all Skype installs and Snaps.

What is going on?

Answer (score 6):

SOVLED:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.save
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer for the question , So others that have the same issue can solve it too. But how can i do that ? You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).

Answer (score 3):

`1F3045A5DF7587C3` key is no longer valid which can be removed using `apt-key del` command.

**Step 1:** Delete the invalid key:

```
sudo apt-key del 1F3045A5DF7587C3
```

If anyone has Skype running but facing the signature verification error while running `sudo apt update` command then continue with the below steps.

**Step 2:** Add a valid key:

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Step 3:** Run the below commands:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

This error should be removed now!

Comment: I think you need to highlight on point of Running `apt-get update` before Step #2 as I follow the steps but did not work (Without running the update command after removing the old Key) first.

Comment: Also, Can you mention solving the Skype expired Key instead of Removing the enter Skype program to hide the display error when running `apt-get update` command? his comment https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347366/removed-skype-still-have-apt-get-update-errors-about-skype#comment2302776_1347369 is correct