# How to get rid of skype completely and for good? GPG error

Tags: 22.04, skype, software-uninstall

I got big problems with Skype application on **ubuntu 22.04**. There was a lot of bugs and I finally decided to remove this app and switch to web version. I uninstalled this but skype still hold to something in my system.

When I am trying to execute: **sudo apt update**
I get this:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                         
Hit:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                       
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                             
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                           
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                     
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                  
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Err:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
Fetched 110 kB in 6s (18,2 kB/s)                                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I dont't want to see this warning anymore. I just want to get rid off this and also know how to deal with this kind of problem in the future.

I was trying to do this ([Removed skype still have apt get update errors about skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347366/removed-skype-still-have-apt-get-update-errors-about-skype)):

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.save
```

but:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list': Operation not permitted
```

Can anyone help me with this? So annoying...

---

Updates:

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list  skype-stable.list
docker.list                       skype-stable.list.save
docker.list.save                  vscode.list
google-chrome.list                vscode.list.save
google-chrome.list.save
```

Comment: Look under **all** of the `.list` files under `/etc/apt` especially `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the sources for Skype.

Comment: @Nmath Under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Please add output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot What is the confusion? `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is under `/etc/apt` OP needs to remove offending entries from any source list in this directory or any subdirectories.

Comment: Did you edit the /etc/apt/sources.list.d and remove any entries for skype. It is a file that controls what PPA s will be used on update. Your command does not edit the file it tries to remove some file that is most likely not there.

Comment: I edited my post @Pilot6

Comment: @David yes I was doing something following instructions from other posts but that I don't remember what I did exactly :/

Comment: Whatever problems you had with Skype was likely due to NOT updating it because the repo needed coorection. Actually the repo wasn't needed at all, it must have come from old outdated instructions. Skype is now available as a SNAP, updated and working fine. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

Okay my fix was answer from that post:
[Permission denied: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031553/permission-denied-etc-apt-sources-list-d-google-earth-list)

The file was immutable I have no idea why.

I executed this command to find out this file was immutable:

```
$ lsattr /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
----i--------e-- /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

after that I removed file immutability:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

and finally deleted it:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

Comment: Please post the actions you did. Otherwise the answer will be deleted by mods. It will be a good answer.